# SQL Server DBLlink to oracle returns numbers as string

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have an Oracle database containing my data and an SQL Server database getting the data from Oracle through DBLink.
Problem is - all numbers from the Oracle tables are accepted at the SQL Server as nvarchar. As a result, when i try to filter the query in the SQL Server with some_number_field = 0 i get:
"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3.141' to data type int."
This also happens if i try to select "some_number_field * 1" or similar expressions.
Any idea ?

Comment: Is SQL Server getting data? So I suppose it is linked server.

Comment: sorry, I did not understand. what so you mean by "it is linked server" ?
I have a dblink in the SQL Server retrieving data from oracle but the formats go wrong...

Comment: I also so that when the column type in Oracle is 'number(3,0)' it is ok, the problem is only when the oracle column type is just 'number'

Answer (score 1):

Today I ran into the same kind of problem. It seems that Oracle field with datatype NUMBER are shown as nvarchar where querying through a linked server. However, NUMBER(x,y) not.

E.g. colB is the NUMBER field from an Oracle View (or table)
Try this:

```
SELECT colA, CAST(colB AS DECIMAL(23,2)) colB
FROM OPENQUERY(LINKED_SERVER_NAME, 'select * from myView')
```

Note: the DECIMAL(xx,y) values depends of course on your data. Also, remember, if your NUMBER column is a repetitive fraction (eg. 33.33333333 etc), you need to place a round() on the oracle side otherwise the CAST will throw an error.